# Can I get all the documents from documentdb in azure functions without specifying their id's?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cloud-services, azure-functions

I want to get all the documents from Azure documentDB in Azure Function. Is it possible ? I am using Node.js. If it is possible then how can I do it ?

Comment: I don't think this question is too broad. There is a single correct answer, "No, that's not possible now but it may be in the future".

Comment: Manish, please clarify your question to be specific about the DocumentDB input binding which I assume it is. Then my answer below is correct, and this question is not too broad.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. Actually I want to get total count of number of documents present in my documentDB collection in an interval of every 1 minute. Is there any other way to do that ( I don't want to do it on premise) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, our DocumentDB input binding only supports binding to a **single document** by ID. We have an issue tracking in our repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/289) to add support for allowing binding to multiple items, as well as supporting queries.

Feel free to chime in on that issue with more details on your scenarios. Thanks :) I agree with you that we should improve this ASAP.

Comment: Thanks @mathewc for your kind help. Actually I want to get total count of number of documents present in my documentDB collection in an interval of every 1 minute. Is there any other way to do that ( I don't want to do it on premise) ?

Comment: You could try using the nodejs Document DB library directly from within your function code. https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node

Comment: You could also check out DocumentDB's new Change Feed functionality. 1) Detect changes that are relevant in our DocDB instance. 2) Push a simple "count updated" notification to an Azure Event Hub or Queue. 3) Receive notification in your Azure Function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-change-feed